# Different Feeds Tamper per destination in mapping

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a csv feeds importer I'm trying to build where I would like the last 2 digits of a code to be mapped to the task code field, but the full 4 or 5 digit number be mapped to the GUID.

From the interface I can only see a way to run the tamper on the source field for all destinations.[image: screenshot of interface]  Is there some way I can tamp in different ways for different destination fields?  (or tamp for one destination, and use the raw value for another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing this morning, I realized what [Map to multiple fields using 'Blank source'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2614786) in the documentation means.  I was able to have Task Code as my source for GUID, then Blank Source 1 as my source for Task Code.

In the tamper for Blank Source 1 I use Copy Source Value before doing my other transform:

[image: The Tamper List]

---

[image: Copy Source Value Settings]

Answer (score 0):

[Aram Boyajyan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8623/aram-boyajyan) wrote a nice article on how to create a [custom tamper plugin](https://www.aram.cz/article/feeds-tamper-plugin-getting-feed-language).

```
function YOUR_MODULE_tamper_language_callback($result, $item_key, $element_key, &$field, $settings, $source) {
```

*perhaps* one of these callback params holds the destination? something for you investigate.

If yes, then you would just do an if statement.

Comment: @UltraBob cool, it has been a while since I've used feeds. `First thing this morning, I realized` that happens to me too, sometimes sleep fixes everything.